# Make '/' mount shared permanently inside Docker/Podman container

Tags: docker, fedora, podman

I'm following https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/podman-inside-container, targeting rootless Podman running a rootless Podman container. `podman info` works, but shows the warning message

> WARN[0000] "/" is not a shared mount, this could cause issues or
> missing mounts with rootless containers

`mount --make-rshared /`, run as root, solves that. My question is, how I can prepare my image so that I don't need root privileges everytime I run the image.

I tried `RUN mount --make-rshared /` in the Dockerfile. That failed with "Permission denied", which confuses me because permisison is not denied for everything else, like `yum`, `useradd` and file access.

I also tried to put the command in an init script, saved it in `/etc/init.d` and added it with `chkconfig`. It doesn't seem to be executed when I run the image, although I added all runlevels: `123456` . I can execute it directly, but of course only as root.

I'm rather new to Docker/Podman. There are some other question marks for me, like the missing shell commands `login` and `runlevel`. The important goal is to get rid of the warning message though.

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]?  A Docker container is a wrapper around a single process; it's not a full-fledged VM, it doesn't run init scripts, "runlevel" isn't a concept that makes sense, and you don't "log in" to it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for the delay. I can't offer a reasonably small reproducable example at this point. However, Your insights actually got me a step further, I went for a rootful container in rootless Podman, where I dont' see that warning.